# Transfer entire Catalog in Magento

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, magento-1.7

I've a Magento powered website that holds like 300 products and 20 categories in the catalog. Now I need to move that categories and products to another Magento installation. What is the best way to do that? I found many materials about import/export Magento tools but they doesn't works. Probably there's a better way.

Comment: I have been using Magmi to import items.  I have roughly 90,000 items and it takes about 20 minutes to do it.  http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you elaborate on what doesn't work about importing/exporting?

I would first recommend using dataflow profiles over the import/export utilities, specifically Export/Import All Products. Going from one Magento Installation to another **shouldn't be an issue** using dataflow (assuming the versions aren't too varied). Usually it's messing with data from a non Mage installation that's the hard part.

Comment: Dan, the problem is that after an import/export of the catalog and no errors occurred, I can't see the products in Magento admin. Have you got a tutorial for exporting and importing the entire catalog of a Mage installation?

Answer (score 0):

You should use uRapidFlow from Unirgy. It's a bit expensive but it does the job very well and very quickly!

Comment: Thanks for the reply but no thanks, I don't want spend hundreds of dollars for a common scenario like that.